# Typescript eslint disable no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am working on a Typescript React project and I usually put placeholder variables into the code so everything is laid out until I get to implementing everything. This leads to a bunch of `eslint no-unused-vars` errors and makes finding real errors a challage.

How can I disable this globally until I am ready for it? I used `create-react-app my-app --typescript` and don't want to eject the project but not sure how to disable this warning.

I noticed there is a `eslintConfig` section in the `package.json` so I tried to turn off the error there but it doesn't seem to work, is there a command I need to run after editing the `package.json` or is my syntax incorrect?

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
 },
```

### Update

---

(removed `tsconfig.json` reference)

I updated my `package.json` and keep getting the errors.

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
```

I tried moving the rules into a `.eslintrc.json` file in the root of the project and still doesn't seem to turn this off.

The only thing that seems to work is putting `// eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` after the variable.

Comment: there should be tslint.json if not you try creating one with rules you want in there

Comment: @Rikin Do I need to put an entry into the `package.json` to reference this file or is it supposed to find it automatically? I tried making a `tslint.json` in my app's root with the rules section from above and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Its supposed to find automatic, its handled by underlying webpack. If you used `create-react-app` it should have already created one for you. I just did that and it did it for me

Answer (score 45):

I think there is some confusion.

Both the question and the only answer suggest putting a rules section in the `tsconfig.json`.  This is something I've never heard of, and it is not mentioned in the docs or in the [official schema](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Also, the question is about disabling the rule in eslint so the rule change should go in the `.eslintrc.json` file (or the `eslintConfig` section in the `package.json` as considered in the question).

But this is typescript and typescript-eslint so the rule should be:

```
> "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars" : "off"
```

And the hacky solution proposed in an answer that someone linked to needs to be changed to (note that answer is about eslint for js, not ts).

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
```

And those solutions work for me using...

```
+-- eslint@6.5.1  
+-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.3.2  
+-- @typescript-eslint/parser@2.3.2
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, I tried both of your suggestions and I still get the messages, do I need to do anything to get the compiler to recognize the changes or an area that might be overriding this?

Comment: Are you running eslint from the cmdline or just using it in your IDE?  When I'm having problems I try to get it working from the cmdline first.

Comment: Thanks! I just wasted a lot of time before reading your answer and realizing that I was modifying the eslint version instead of the typescript-eslint version...

Comment: Now that I know that there is eslint and there is typescript-eslint, it all makes sense (which is not super obvious when reading the docs and sample configs). Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. Here is my solution:

1. rename `.eslintrc[.json]` to `.eslintrc.js`
2. add `module.exports =`  infront of previous Json object. So `.eslintrc.js` looks like that:

```
module.exports = { 
    ...
    "rules": {...},
    ... 
}
```

3. set `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars"` rule depending on your current environment. This can be achieved by checking the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable. My choice was to get an error in production and be warned in other cases.  The snippet looks like this:

```
module.exports = { 
    ...
    "rules": {
         ...
         "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "warn"
    },
    ... 
}
```

Comment: This is actually the only solution that worked for me ("react-scripts": "4.0.3").

Comment: A very smart solution. ty

Answer (score 8):

You can Add rule in package.json file

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": 0,
   "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you used `create-react-app my-app --typescript` there should already be `tsconfig.json` created for you in your `my-app/`

In your `tsconfig.json` you can add rules for your typescript compiler.

```
{
  "extends": [...],
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [...],
  "rules": {
    ...
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside eslintrc.json add "rules" inside that you just have to write  no-unused-vars to 0.

```
"rules":{
     "no-unused-vars":0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go into your settings and search for 'eslint', then look for something called Elint:enable, uncheck the box which states 'Controls whether eslint is enabled or not.'

It worked for me
I am using

```
Version: 1.72.2 (system setup)
Commit: d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075
Date: 2022-10-12T22:15:18.074Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No
```

Answer (score -3):

if you are using Create-react-app, there is no need to install anything or Eject, you just need to go to `/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js.`
on "new ESLintPlugin" rules just add :

```
'react/jsx-uses-react': 'error',
'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'error',
'no-unused-vars': 0
```