# "Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved"

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, create-react-app, eslintrc

#### 0. April 2023: the error can no longer be [reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

The error is no longer reproducible.
Presumably because of bug fixes in *react-scripts* 5.0.1. <sup>1</sup> 
Although it's no longer reproducible, the question and my [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362095) still [seems to be of interest to users of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71352590#comment132191977_71362095), and [possibly others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71352590#comment133322108_71362095).

I will leave the question largely as it was when I asked it in March 2022.

The zip file containing the source files of the React app is [here](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/StackOverflow-Q71352590/71352590.zip?raw=true).
The only difference compared to 2022 is that I've replaced the *react-scripts* version 4.0.3 with 5.0.1.

## All below refers to March 2022

In Visual Studio Code, I get
`Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved`.

#### *What actions would fix this error?*

I provide my `.eslintrc.json` and `package.json` files in Section 2 below.

Run `npm install` to install the project locally. <sup>2</sup> 
– This may take about 1–9 minutes, depending on your bandwidth and hardware. 
Then `npm start` should open the project in the default web browser.

When I did this and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, I got no errors but two warnings in the console of the browser.

The warnings are in line with the rules in `.eslintrc.json` (Section 2 below) :

- `'unUsedArgument' is defined but never used. Allowed unused args must match /^_/u           no-unused-vars`, and
- `'unUsedVariable' is assigned a value but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_/u  no-unused-vars`.

[image: Running 'npm start' gives 2 warnings, but no error]

#### 1. Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

The error in the title had nothing to do with my choice of text editor. 
This was easily confirmed by running ESLint from the command line.

```
$ npx eslint src
… Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved …
```

[image: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved]

#### 2. Configuration files

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "parsing-error",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`.eslintrc.json` :

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### 3. The error in Visual Studio Code

The error, `Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved`, also shows up when I open `App.js` in VS Code.

[image: Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved]

I am using Visual Studio Code.
But, as already noted, the choice of text editor or IDE doesn't matter.
Note that – in addition to installing ESLint correctly via `npm` – you also have to install a plugin/extension for your specific integrated development environment (IDE). 
In my case, I use [the official VS Code ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).

#### References

- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [One of my self-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362095)
- [Zip file containing the needed project files](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/blob/main/StackOverflow-Q71352590/71352590.zip?raw=true)
- [Installing ESLint *globally* (`npm install eslint --global`) is *not recommended*](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started#global-install)
- [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev)
- [How ESLint is integrated into Create React App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006)
- [VS Code ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)
- [Parsing Error The Keyword import is Reserved (SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36002226)
- [The react-scripts npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)
- [`eslint-config-react-app`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app)
- [`@babel/eslint-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/eslint-parser)
- [The Community FAQ index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225)
- [What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252254)
- [An implicit definition of when a question is a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495)
- [The highest voted answer of other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41190209)
- [The deprecated `babel-eslint` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-eslint)
- [Installing ESLint globally might be a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36214267)
- [You absolutely should not be installing `react-scripts` globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890)

---

<sup>1</sup>
When I originally asked the question, *react-scripts* 4.0.3 was the latest version. 
If I now use version 4.0.3, then I get other errors that have nothing to do with the question asked.

<sup>2</sup>
It's [recommended to install ESLint *locally*](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started#global-install).
This is what [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev) does. 
For more information on how Create React App uses ESLint, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006).
*[You absolutely should not be installing `react-scripts` globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

##### Disclaimer

As stated in the question, the error can no longer be reproduced. 
This means there is no longer any valid suggestion to resolve the error. 
I leave the rest of the answer mainly unaltered, in case others still find it helpful. <sup>*</sup>

#### The original answer

Here is a simple solution – just move the `rules` attribute from
`.eslintrc.json` to the `eslintConfig` attribute of `package.json`.
<sup>1</sup>

And *don't keep* `.eslintrc.json`. *Just delete it!*
<sup>2</sup>

The `package.json` file will now be as follows.

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "parsing-error",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": [
        "warn",
        {
          "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
          "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version"
    ]
  }
}
```

That's it!
<sup>3</sup>

Check to see that you were successful : \

```
npx eslint **/*.js
```

Expect to see :

[image: Using eslintConfig in package.json makes the error go away.]

No error. – *Yay!*

If your text editor (VS Code in my case) is still open, make sure that you restart it before expecting to see the error go away!

#### References

- [A more cumbersome solution to the question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71352591)
- [Suggesting to have ESLint `rules` in `package.json` under  `eslintConfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58098637)
- [Installation of ESLint using `npm`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint#installation-and-usage)
- [ESLint's new config system – the path forward](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-1/#the-path-forward)
- [ESLint gets installed even though it isn't explicitly mentioned in  `package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006)

---

<sup>*</sup>
The one thing I've changed is the command for running ESLint from the command line – `npx eslint **/*.js` has the advantage of working fine for the new `eslint.config.js` file (["flat config](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-1/#the-path-forward)") as well as for the old `.eslintrc.*` configuration files.

<sup>1</sup>
I got the idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58098637).

<sup>2</sup>
Don't run `npm init @eslint/config` either.
The error(s) will persevere if you don't delete `.eslintrc.json`!

<sup>3</sup>
A. If you suspect that you may have a *global* installation of ESLint, first run: 
`npm uninstall eslint --global`

B. If you have already run `npm install` – as suggested on line 7 of the question – then you shouldn't need to run `npm install eslint --save-dev` to install ESLint, because having `react-scripts` in `package.json` means that [*ESLint gets installed when running `npm install`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006).

Comment: this worked like a charm in a huge angular project (including "prettier" and cypress) as well. let's upvote this to no end.

Comment: It is an epic Q&A combo. I were just trying to ignore this error, but to no avail. Working as a charm on Windows 11, and VSC 1.75.1. It fixed error on WebStorm 2022.2.4 too. Congrats and thanks

Answer (score 1):

### 0. Disclaimers

This answer has its share of bad advice and flaws.
I rather strongly suggest having a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362095) before continuing to read here.
Some of the problems with this answer include :

- It's much longer and more cumbersome than the other answer.
- This solution suggests creating a `.eslintrc.json` file, which makes
  it less elegant and less robust than the other answer.
- Instead of just fixing the original error, this solution leads to
  *two new errors*, which in turn need to be dealt with.
- When I wrote this answer, I was somewhat ignorant about
  [Create React App, which is one of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/create-react-app/info)
  of the question asked.
  For example, installing ESLint doesn't make any sense, since
  [ESLint is already automatically included in *every* Create React App
  project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006).

I've thought about deleting this answer altogether, but since it has
received an upvote, and  since it's not in my interest to delete it,
I've decided to leave it undeleted for the time being.

This *Disclaimers* section is my honest attempt not to mislead anyone.

#### 1. Prerequisites

If the server is running, close it by hitting
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I strongly recommend *uninstalling* any *global* installations of
ESLint.
To see what global packages are installed, in the command line run:
<sup>1</sup>

```
npm list --global --depth 0
```

If ESLint is globally installed, uninstall it by running:

```
npm uninstall eslint --global
```

To correctly install ESLint into your local project, I recommend
performing the following two steps.

1. Locally install ESLint.
2. Create a functioning `.eslintrc.json` file.

As it turns out, you will also need to do a third step.

3. Update all `npm` packages to their latest versions.

#### 2. Locally install ESLint

To locally install ESLint, run:
<sup>2</sup>

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

This will add

```
  ,
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0"
  }
```

at the end of `package.json`.

#### 3. Create a `.eslintrc.json` file that works

*NOTE!* Before moving on, do yourself a favor by saving a copy of your
current `.eslintrc.json` file, as the following command will destroy
(recreate) that file.

To create a new `.eslintrc.json` file, run:

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

You'll be asked several questions, to which I answer by pressing
<kbd>Enter</kbd> to choose the default, *except* for the *format*
which I choose to be `JSON` (instead of `JavaScript`).

[image: Configuring ESLint]

In addition to creating the `.eslintrc.json` file, this will also add
the `"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.2"` attribute under
`devDependencies` to the `package.json` file.
<sup>3</sup>

The command `npm init @eslint/config` destroys the existing
`.eslintrc.json` file, so you will have to manually add back any
`"rules"` or other JSON settings that you want to keep.
In this case, I add back the rules that were in the original
`.eslintrc.json`.
The result is as below.

`.eslintrc.json` :

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I open VS Code, instead of an error there are two warnings,
which is exactly the desired outcome.

[image: VS Code now displaying two warnings but no errors]

*Great!* But wait – unfortunately there turns out to be a fly in the
ointment.
The problem is that when I now run `npm start` to open the project in
the web browser and hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, two errors show up in the
console.
The error messages are:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`, and
- `Line 0:  Parsing error: ImportDeclaration should appear when the mode is ES6 and in the module context`.

Luckily, I have already posted a solution to this problem, namely:
[Update all `npm` packages to their latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335761).
The section below is a bit succinct, so if you want more flesh on the
bones, go visit [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335761).

#### 4. Update all `npm` packages to their latest versions

Consider updating all `npm` packages to their latest versions.
The purpose is to decrease the risk of getting version conflicts.
The advice to *update all packages* has also been put forth in
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767239).

*A. Globally install `npm-check-updates`*

In the command line, run:

```
npm install --global npm-check-updates
```

*B. Update `package.json` to contain the latest versions*

The following command will write the latest package version numbers to
your `package.json`:

```
npm-check-updates --upgrade
```

Here is what it looks like in Windows 10:

[image: Upgrading package.json]

*C. Install the latest versions*

In the command line, run:

```
npm install
```

*D. Check for errors in the browser and/or in the terminal*

In the command line, run:

```
npm start
```

Both the browser and the terminal now display *five errors*.

**Discomforting, eh?**

Yes definitely! – *But don't give up hope!*
Just close the server (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and try it over
and over again.
Yesterday when I got these errors, all I needed to do was to run
`npm start` *one* more time.
Today I tried running`npm start` 4-5 more times, but still got the
errors.
So I tried `npm install && npm start` twice, and finally it
ran without errors.
Not sure what is going on. Maybe some time has to pass before it works?

Finally, there are *no errors* in the browser.

[image: NO errors in the web browser!]

And the terminal says *Compiled successfully!*

[image: The terminal says: 'Compiled successfully!']

*Yay!*
<sup>4</sup>

#### 5. Conclusion

Following the steps above helped me remedy the error in the question
title:
*Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved*.

For a project with settings even slightly different,<sup>5</sup> just
copy-pasting from the `.eslintrc.json` file above  is unlikely to
work.
Running `npm init @eslint/config` and upgrading all packages is more
likely to be successful.

### References

- [A better, shorter, more elegant, and more robust answer to the
  question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362095)
- [ESLint is already automatically included in *every*
  Create React App project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71423006)
- [Info on the [create-react-app] tag at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/create-react-app/info)
- [`npm` – get a list of globally installed packages](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/javascript/npm-get-list-globally-installed-packages/)
- [Installation of ESLint using `npm`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint#user-content-installation-and-usage)
- [Start using `@eslint/config` in your project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eslint/create-config)
- [When should I use `@babel/eslint-parser`?](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#when-should-i-use-babeleslint-parser)
- [Update all `npm` packages to their latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335761)
- [Update all current packages to their latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767239)
- [`npm-check-updates` – documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

---

<sup>1</sup> I am on Windows 10, but I expect all the commands
provided here to work just as fine on both Linux and macOS.

<sup>2</sup>
A. Expect this command to take about 5-10 minutes to complete.
B. As long as your source code is *not* transformed by Babel,
there is no reason to install `@babel/eslint-parser`.
Just normal `eslint` should be enough.
See [When should I use `@babel/eslint-parser`?](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#when-should-i-use-babeleslint-parser)
If you are using TypeScript, then you will need
`@babel/eslint-parser`.
The command to install is:
`npm install eslint @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev`
The `npm init @eslint/config` configuration command should be used
in the same way as for the normal (*non*-@babel) ESLint.

<sup>3</sup> The `"eslint-plugin-react"` attribute in `package.json`
doesn't seem to be of much relevance though.

<sup>4</sup> The two warnings still show up in the text editor –
just as they should.

<sup>5</sup>
For example, you might be using Angular or Vue instead of React.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error message on a third-party js file in my angular app. I have eslint already installed. I updated my .eslintrc.json to add "*.js" to the "overrides" --> "files" array and the error went away.

```
{
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.js", "*.ts"],
        }
    ]
}
```